# Problem importing LiDAR data in GRASS 7

Tags: grass-gis, import, lidar, las, liblas

I compiled GRASS 7 on Ubuntu 12.10, with liblas in order to run `r.in.lidar` and `v.in.lidar`. I now want to import .las data; the option in file -> import raster data -> LAS LIDAR points import is given and enabled, but when I select it nothing happens.

It seems to be a problem with libLAS. The console error message says:

> Unable to fetch interface description for command 'r.in.lidar'. Details: r.in.lidar: error while loading shared libraries: liblas_c.so.2.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Addition: running lasinfo from terminal works.

Any idea where the bug could be?

Comment: Please check the console for error messages and post them here (bu editing your posting).

Comment: Seems to be a problem with liblas:
Unable to fetch interface description for command
'r.in.lidar'.
Details: r.in.lidar: error while loading shared libraries:
liblas_c.so.2.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
file or directory

Comment: Addition: running lasinfo from terminal works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. 
Did a `make clean` (that is what I omitted before), then again 
`$ "-g -Wall" ./configure --with-liblas=/usr/local/bin/liblas-config`, followed by `make` and `sudo make install`. Works now!

Comment: Excellent (note that "male distclean" is better to really clean up stuff). Please accept your answer to close the issue here.