# GRASS r.in.lidar problem on Windows 10: 'no such file or directory'

Tags: grass-gis, import, lidar, las, grass-7.0

I'm having problems to load .las files into Grass GIS 7.0.3 for Windows 10. I use the module `r.in.lidar` but I get the following message:

[image]

What can I do? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does 'r.in.lidar --help' in the command tab work?

Comment: Also posted on grass-user mailing list. Now answered and solved. I suggest you to answer the question and accept the answer, so this shows as solved.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @wenzeslaus this question was asked on [grass-user mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-February/073692.html) and it was answered.

According to Martin Landa, it happened that on 64 bit installations the liblas_c.dll file was not available. Then, the build environment was updated and the OP there confirmed the problem was solved.

A re-package of GRASS 7.0.3 to include liblas for 64 bit installator was planned.

---

<sub>Related question, with similar but not equal error message:</sub>
<sub>[Problem importing LiDAR data in GRASS 7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55378/problem-importing-lidar-data-in-grass-7)</sub>